# How do I compare specific data to multiple columns(rather than just one) using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code that allows me to search given data in a specific cell against the data for all rows in one column of another sheet in the same workbook. I would like to expand the search to columns 2 and 3 (B and C). I have tried different methods of expanding the range of the search but I keep getting errors. I am new to using VBA so please go easy on me. Im sure that im just missing something simple here.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ItemID()

Dim SearchPage As Worksheet
Dim AllORingData As Worksheet
Dim dashnumber As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set SearchPage = Sheet2
Set AllORingData = Sheet6
dashnumber = SearchPage.Range("C4").Value

SearchPage.Range("A10:F500").ClearContents

AllORingData.Select
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 1) Like dashnumber Then
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).Copy
    SearchPage.Select
    Range("A500").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    AllORingData.Select
    End If

Next i

SearchPage.Select

Range("C4").Select

End Sub
```

If I replace:

```
If Cells(i, 1) Like dashnumber Then
```

With:

```
If Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)) Like dashnumber Then
```

I get the error

> Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch

I have done some reading about this error and what I understand is that it's looking for either an Integer or a string and it is getting the wrong thing. The data I am searching contains colons, semi-colons, commas, dashes and numbers.

Comment: Use either `And` or `Or`: `If Cells(i, 1) Like dashnumber And Cells(i, 2) Like dashnumber And Cells(i, 3) Like dashnumber Then`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you very much. I used Or like you suggested and it worked just the way I needed it to. I would upvote your comment but it looks like I need more rep for that.